# Cannot login to MSQL via localhost, CAN via 127.0.0.7 since Lion (OS X 10.7.4 ug)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, osx-lion

I've recently upgraded to OS X 10.7.4 from Snow Leopard.

Since then, MySQL can't be accessed via 'localhost' when that is specified as the 'host' for Wordpress sites and PHPMyAdmin etc. If I use 127.0.0.1 it works ok.

A few notes / tests:
- Apache is running and accessible on "http://localhost" (and tons of other vhosts)
- I do know the mysql root pass and can login with that using "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u 'root' -p"
- If I ping localhost it does resolve to 127.0.0.1.

What should I check or report back to troubleshoot this further? Is there a my.ini or my.cnf file that I need to add 'localhost' to? I've tried to find/locate both those and they don't seem to be present.

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Comment: Programming Tools (IDE's, ORM's, source-code control systems and the like) are on-topic. Databases are really sort of one-step removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you log into mysql, execute the following queries...

```
UPDATE mysql.user
SET Host = '%'
WHERE User = 'root';
```

Sometimes I need to do this (below) when I mess around with MYSQL DB tables, but it is most likely irrelevant for your situation:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Restart MySQL server (service) if that is an option. Then try to access MySQL through 127.0.0.1 or localhost. ***Warning: the above command is probably OK to run on a development machine but definitely not on a production server!***

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I executed the update you suggested and get the following response: "Duplicate entry '%-root' for key 'PRIMARY'". Do you know why this is?

Comment: Run this SQL `SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user`. That will yield list of users and hosts they can remotely connect to MySQL. It is possible you had more than one entry for `root` user, so it refused to update all the records. For development purposes, I need a single user, so I delete all other entries. Ensure you have 1 record with `root` and `%`. If so, then execute the following SQL command (if you think it makes sense): `DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='root'  AND Host<>'%'`.